# ¿«Volador de luces»(evento) y «Tirar la pelota para el/al córner»(acción) están relacionados en Chile?

Tags: expresiones, chile, significado-en-contexto, modismos

Como lo entiendo, *volador de luces* es el **evento** y *tirar la pelota para el córner* es la **acción**.

- **Volador de luces** sería un **evento** que busca **desviar la atención** de otro u otros porque éste/éstos está(n) perjudicando a un determinado sector o persona, por ej: "El gobierno sigue tirando *voladores de luces* para tratar de desviar la atención del verdadero problema de fondo"//"La propuesta que están haciendo **esquiva el bulto**, en el fondo es un volador de luces."

> El propio personal beneficiado con este proyecto enviado por el Ejecutivo, lo ha rechazado, por estimarlo que estaba fuera de foco y que era un simple "**volador de luces**", ellos desean que se les mejoren sus sueldos, pero en forma racional y no fuera de toda lógica, como ocurre con el proyecto enviado por el Ejecutivo...

- **Tirar la pelota para el córner** sería la **acción** con la cual una persona o sector busca *desentenderse* cuando son emplazados. Por ej: El presidente hizo un chiste *desubicado* o *de mal gusto* y cuando a la ministra le preguntan sobre este hecho *fuera de lugar*, respondió hablando sobre otra cosa **desentendiéndose de** aquel hecho o **eludiendo** la pregunta, **desviando la atención** hacia otros temas para no afectar más su propio sector político.

Sin embargo, **tirar la pelota para el córner** también lo he visto usada para referirse una acción **fuera de lugar**, es decir:

- El diputado emplazó al senador. El ministro dice que el acto del diputado de emplazar al senador es *tirar la pelota para el córner*, pero en este caso con el sentido de algo *nada que ver*, *fuera de lugar* o que lo que hace es un *despropósito* porque según el ministro con ese acto el diputado sólo busca *figurar* porque no conoce a fondo lo que está sucediendo o solamente busca *cuestionar* el desempeño del senador.

> Los dirigentes partidarios están llamados a conducir y mediar, no a **tirar la pelota al córner**.

¿«Volador de luces»(evento) y «tirar la pelota para el córner»(acción) están relacionados en Chile?

Comment: "Tirar la pelota para el córner" = dilatar, demorar, desentenderse, desviar la atención. Literalmente interrumpe el ataque del contrincante, detiene el juego y obliga a una jugada de cierto peligro pero que puede ser mejor defendida (puede haber llegado el resto del equipo). Yo diría que tiene una acepción más cercana a "bajar la presión" que a "distraer". No me parece que tenga el sentido de algo fuera de lugar, más bien interrumpir o desviar una cierta acción dando tiempo para organizar una mejor defensa. Podría decirse que es menos "honroso" que seguir jugando tratando de contraatacar.

Answer (score 1):

Un "volador de luces" es una distracción. "Tirarla al córner" es una dilación. En ambos casos el objetivo es interrumpir un ataque sin contestarlo, sin entrar al fondo del asunto.